# datatable excel export button not working properly when header contain select menu

Tags: datatable

im using datatable with its extension buttons for exporting excel. im having select menu filter on some columns. when data is exported to excel , it contains all options in select menu in header. i just want the header name and dont know what to do

here is the code:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsoft/60nu7wxe/22/)

i test multi header like this

```
<thead>
<tr> data without select menu</tr>
<tr> data with select menu</tr>
<thead>
```

but it did not work ;

.

Comment: "it did not work". _How_ does this not work? What are you trying to do, what did you try, and what results did you get?

Comment: please see the jsfiddle. get excel export and look at the header of excel file. the header contain all cell values in name column. i just want header contain table title